# How to iterate over HTML DOM nodes that contain one of the provided attributes?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I want to be able to get the first matching element, then the second, and so on, for the following CSS selector:

```
[att]
```

The below selectors are not valid CSS3 selectors, but that is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
   [att][0]
   [att][1]
   ...
   [att][n]
```

Can I combine multiple selectors and iterate over each matching node just like the example above?

```
[att1],[att2]
```

If this can't be done with native DOM or CSS3 selectors, then an XPath query is also an option.

Comment: I don't understand your `[att1,att2]` selector. Don't you want to iterate elements matching only one attribute selector?

Comment: For starters I just want to iterate over nodes that match one attribute. Ex [href][0], [href][1].

Comment: To combine multiple attribute selectors use `[att1], [att2]` for elements that have either one or both, or `[att1][att2]` for elements that must have both.

Comment: Ok. and how do I get the nth element that matched that selector?

Comment: Well there's no CSS selector for that so you'll need to use DOM functions to do that. With jQuery it's a no-brainer, but I assume you know how, and would like a native DOM solution instead (which I'm not able to provide).

Comment: @Nael - It would probably help if you showed us a visual of what you're trying to accomplish using the method you've explained.

Comment: I have to use native JavaScript / DOM or CSS3 selectors to pick out elements that match the attributes I'm looking for. Currently I'm fetching all DOM nodes and checking each one for the attributes I'm looking for. This gets slow on larger pages.

Comment: This is *not* an XPath question.

Comment: @Dimitre no, but XPath is an option to do the same kind of query. Anyway, the answer below with CSS3 and JS works for me. How would you do this with an XPath selector?

Comment: @Nael El Shawwa: Re: "How would you do this with an XPath selector?" First of all "XPath selector" doesn't mean anything to me. Secondly, What do you mean by "this"? If you ask me how to select a specific set of nodes in an XML document, then this *is* an XPath question and I would be able to help. However, the current question doesn't provide an XML document and doesn't specifiy what set of nodes should be selected. I don't understand at all what the question is asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase. How would you iterate over a set of tags in an HTML (XML) document that contain a set of attributes. Say I want to iterate over all <p> tags in an HTML document that contain the attribute "onclick" or "href" or "src". I found a solution with a CSS3 query. Out of curiosity what would an XPath query to do that query and iterate over the results look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `document.querySelectorAll()` is an option, it will be very easy — just pass the selector and the browser will handle the rest:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('[att]');

for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; ++i) {
    alert(elms[i].tagName);
}
```

It works with any CSS selector you pass it provided the browser supports it (which in this case any browser implementing the function should already do). So to pick elements that have either `att1`, `att2` or both, use this as mentioned in the comments:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('[att1], [att2]');
```

Comment: Brilliant! document.querySelectorAll('[href],[onclick]')[10];

Comment: Just be aware that this isn't supported in IE7 or FF3

Comment: And that attribute selectors were introduced in CSS2.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('[att]');
```

Also, this works:

```
$('[att1],[att2]');
```

The first will give you a list of all elements with an `att` attribute.  If you don't want to use jQuery, your code will run ***much*** slower since the logical way to do this is:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0, l=elems.length; i<l; i++){
    if(elems[i].getAttribute('att')){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The reason jQuery is actually faster is because it will use XPath queries or other methods when possible, which will greatly speed up the execution.  Of course you could implement XPath in the above code if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but can't use jQuery. Native CSS3, DOM, or XPath queries only. However, I should try and look how jQuery uses XPath for the query. Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to chain a `.get()` call to the jQuery calls to get a set of DOM elements.

Comment: Curious -- why can't you use jQuery?  You can strip it to the Sizzle engine if you need (4kb minified and gzipped)

Comment: Its for a tool that scans a javascript based web application through a browser for certain DOM nodes. So has to work via standard DOM/JS/CSS3